# fill asp:CheckBoxList from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkboxlist

i have problems filling my checkboxlist from a sql in c#. The list is empty when it have been loaded.

I know it would probably be easier with a connection to web.config, but i have decieded not to have web.config in this project. It would be helpfull if anyone could see what i have done wrong.

This is my code:

```
string connetionString = "Data Source=[DATA-SOURCE];Initial Catalog=[CATALOG];User ID=[USER-ID];Password=[PASSWORD]";
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ModuleID, ModuleName, InternalName, Active FROM dbo.Zodiac_System_Modules WHERE Active = 1 ORDER BY ModuleName ASC";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cnn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();
                item.Text = sdr["ModuleName"].ToString();
                item.Value = sdr["InternalName"].ToString();
                chkModules.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        cnn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: 1. Is the reader actually reading anything ? 2. In which part of the page lifecycle events are you putting this in?

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't pop the data into a table and then databind the DataTable to the listbox?

Comment: any error received ?? i think your code is fine...How You are binding it to `ListItem ` to `CheckBoxList`

Comment: @Haedrian No, it's not reading, and thats what i don't understand. It should run on a ButtonClick.

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar No errors.

Comment: @DanielCasserly No, not really, I have just tried a lot of different ways, and now I buck down and ask for help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sorry, I were not aware of that, it was only to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Are Missing [CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/.../system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) This:

```
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: Beginner's Luck :P OR May be Experience Matters :P hehehe. Have Fun Coding. And I'll Remember this. My First Rating :P Thank you back :)

Comment: That's strange. [CommandType.Text is the default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx). It should not be the problem here.

Comment: @Steve It didn't work before, now it does. 
I don't get it either. No matter what, it helped.

Comment: Well, don't touch anything then :-) (However I would try to remove that line just to see if it stops working)